# "Minimal security" with Active Directory Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, group-policy

I have setup a Raspberry Pi with Samba 4 as a Active Directory Domain Controller on my home network.

But I have a simple question:

Whenever a computer joins my domain it is assign a rather strict security profile from the domain controller.

Like:

- PIN code login is disabled.
- Microsoft Hello is disabled.
- 2FA login disabled, password has to follow a certain syntax.
- Windows update can have "issues" with automatic updates.
- etc.

I know I can change all these settings through Group Policy in the Windows Adminstrative tool set, but it is a rather tedious process of finding each setting one by one, in order the relax security settings a bit.

Is there a way to use a preconfigured profile that basically makes the Windows 10 client act as if it was a freshly installed computer with factory default settings for Windows 10 except logins and group access can be managed from a central place?

Comment: It was actually the default settings when installing Samba as a Active Directory Domain Controller and THEN letting a Windows 10 Professional client join the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddeling a lot more with my computer, I found the answer to be more simple than expected.

The solution was rather simple, since it is posible to disable the default group policy altogether as shown in link:

[Disable default Group Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr1WO.png)

Note I disabled both `Default Domain Controllers Policy`and `Default Domain Policy`, but I suspect less will suffice too.